# Imprimindo árvore binária graficamente em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

Semana passada eu estava mexendo neste código que imprime árvore binária graficamente porem não entendi muito bem sua forma de usar ou se tem algum bug pois digito a quantidade de nós e o algoritmo fica processando e não imprime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct informacao{ //
   int valor;
}informacao;

typedef struct no{
   informacao dado;
   struct no *sub_arvore_esquerda;
   struct no *sub_arvore_direita;
}no;


no * planta_arvore(no *arvore){
   arvore = NULL;
   return(arvore);
}

no * insere(informacao info, no *arvore){
   if(arvore == NULL){
      arvore = (no *)malloc(sizeof(no));
      arvore->dado = info;
      arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda = NULL;
      arvore->sub_arvore_direita= NULL;
      return(arvore);
   }
   if(info.valor < arvore->dado.valor){
       printf("%d inserido na esquerda",arvore->dado.valor);
      arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda=insere(info,arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda);
      return(arvore);
   }
   if(info.valor > arvore->dado.valor){
       printf("%d inserido na direita", arvore->dado.valor);
      arvore->sub_arvore_direita=insere(info,arvore->sub_arvore_direita);
      return(arvore);
   }
   else
      return NULL;
}

int imprime_pre_ordem(no *arvore)
{/// a função ultilizada foi a pre-ordem pois imprime primeiro a raiz, depois segue pela esquerda e depois pela direita 
   int a=1,b=1;
   if(arvore != NULL){
      printf("(");
      printf("%d",arvore->dado.valor);
      a=imprime_pre_ordem(arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda);///a==0 caso sub_arvore_esquerda==NULL
      b=imprime_pre_ordem(arvore->sub_arvore_direita);///a==0 caso sub_arvore_direita==NULL
      if(b==0 && a==0)printf("()");///imprime  () se e somente se encontrar um nó folha
      else if(b==0 && a!=0);///isso acontece se encontrar um nó com a perna direita null
      else if(b!=0 && a==0);///isso acontece se encontrar um nó com a perna esquerda null

     /**Observações:
     Existem tambem mais dois casos:
     1°- Para imprimir quando a perna direita ou esquerda for null 
     ou seja quando as raizes da arvore não estiverem completas basta 
     retirar a condição da linha 50 (obs:só imprimira as "pernas" vazias)e atualizar o resto assim:
     */
     if(b==0 && a!=0)printf("()");
     if(b!=0 && a==0)printf("()");

     /* 2°- Para imprimir quando a perna direita ou esquerda for null ou as duas basta retirar a 
      * condição da linha 50,51,52 e fazer uma condição para cada assim:
      */

     if(b==0)printf("()");
     if(a==0)printf("()");

     /* That's All Folks! (É só isso pessoal!) */
      printf(")");///fecha a representação de uma raiz
   }else return 0;//retorna 0 caso arvore == NULL 
}
//         testes realizados:
//  caso ativado: (15(13(9(6()))(14()))(25(17())(28(27())(31()))))
//  1° caso: (15(13(9(6()())())(14()()))(25(17()())(28(27()())())))
//  2° caso: (15(13(9(6)())(14))(25(17)(28(27)())))
/*
void imprimir(no *arvore){
    printf("(");
    if(arvore == NULL)
        printf("-1"); // imprime -1 se encontrar um no folha
    else{
        printf("%d", arvore->dado.valor);
        imprimir(arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda);
        imprimir(arvore->sub_arvore_direita);
    }
    printf(")");
}
*/
int main()
{
   no *arvore,
   *arv,
   *arv2;
   informacao dado;
   int ret,i;
   printf("quantos nos tem a arvore? ");
   scanf("%d",&ret);
   printf("\n");
   arvore = planta_arvore(arvore);
   for(i=0;i<ret;i++){
      scanf("%d",&dado.valor);
      arvore = insere(dado,arvore);
      if(arvore == NULL);
   }
//     printf("\nEm ordem :");
   imprime_pre_ordem(arvore);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Esse programa inmprime uma arvore graficamente ou seja:

```
         15
       /    \
     13      25
     /\     / \
    9 14   17 28
   /          / \
  6          27 31
```

> Ficaria assim:  (15(13(9(6()))(14()))(25(17())(28(27())(31()))))

Qual é o problema deste algoritmo?

Comment: Selecione todo o código e coloque para ficar em modo de código para ficar legivel, assim fica dificil de dar uma resposta

Comment: mas é o codigo todo que esta ai

Comment: Sim eu sei, mas não estava selecionado como código inteiro, uma parte estava como texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando rapidamente, encontrei os seguintes erros:

- As funções planta_arvore e insere deveriam ser void pois já se recebe um ponteiro e a variável para onde ele aponta já modifica a variável do main.
- Além disso, a variável arvore deve ser do tipo no e não um ponteiro para no.
- if(arvore == NULL); não faz sentido.
- Eu também alteraria a forma de criar a árvore para:

  ```
     void planta_arvore(no *arvore){

       arvore->dado.valor = -1;   
       arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda = NULL;   
       arvore->sub_arvore_direita = NULL;   
     }
  ```

  - E criaria uma função para testar se a árvore está vazia:

    bool esta_vazia(no arvore) {

    ```
    return arvore.sub_arvore_esquerda == NULL && arvore.sub_arvore_direita == NULL;
    ```

    }

  Segue o código alterado:

  typedef struct no{    int dado;    struct no *sub_arvore_esquerda;    struct no *sub_arvore_direita; }no;

  void planta_arvore(no *arvore){    arvore->dado = -1;       arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda = NULL;       arvore->sub_arvore_direita = NULL;    }

  bool esta_vazia(no arvore) {    return arvore.sub_arvore_esquerda == NULL && arvore.sub_arvore_direita == NULL; }

  no * insere(int info, no *arvore){    if(arvore == NULL){
        arvore = (no *)malloc(sizeof(no));
        arvore->dado = info;
        arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda = NULL;
        arvore->sub_arvore_direita= NULL;
        return(arvore);    }    if(info < arvore->dado){
         printf("%d inserido na esquerda",arvore->dado);
        arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda=insere(info,arvore->sub_arvore_esquerda);
        return(arvore);    }    if(info > arvore->dado){
         printf("%d inserido na direita", arvore->dado);
        arvore->sub_arvore_direita=insere(info,arvore->sub_arvore_direita);
        return(arvore);    }    else
        return NULL; }

  int main() {    no arvore;
         int dado;    int ret,i;    printf("quantos nos tem a arvore? ");    scanf("%d",&ret);    printf("\n");    planta_arvore(&arvore);   for(i=0; i

Comment: Eu alterei a função planta_arvore para void e modifiquei ela porem me retorna o seguinte erro: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    arvore = planta_arvore(arvore);
 e se eu voltar para no* da forma como foi modificada da segmentation falt.

Comment: A tua variável arvore do main não deve ser ponteiro, então na hora de chamar o método, deves usar planta_arvore(&arvore) e não deves armazenar o resultado pois ele não retorna nada (é void).

Comment: E no método, precisas declarar com ponteiro: void planta_arvore(no *arvore){

Comment: entao mas é exatamente assim que esta https://pastebin.com/dNH3HcHd

Comment: Coloquei o código que alterei no código, mas ele não formatou direito.

Comment: Agora precisas verificar se está funcionando e implementar o pré-ordem.

Comment: Conseguiu implementar?

Comment: de acordo com o criador do algoritmo nao pois ele era pra imprimir no estilo de uma arvore e nao o fez..